# Get function symbol that will run after keypress

Tags: key-bindings

`describe-key` opens help window with a bunch of info.
I need just to get function symbol or name in elisp.

Ex.

`(lookup-key "<right>")`

desired return value: `'right-char`

Is parsing the output of `describe-key` the easiest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is [`key-binding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html#index-key_002dbinding):

```
(key-binding (kbd "<right>"))
right-char
```

Commands like `describe-key(-briefly)` handle some advanced cases such as automatic [de-shifting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequence-Input.html#index-shift_002dtranslation) (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> → `<right> (translated from <S-right>) runs the command right-char`), [input translations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) (e.g. `"\eOC"` translated to `right`), some mouse events, etc., for which there's no convenient interface that doesn't involve actually reading input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want inputting the key `<right>` to return the symbol `right-char` then yes, `lookup-key` does that for you. But you need to call it correctly. It requires two arguments, a keymap and a key description.

- Presumably you want the global key binding, so the keymap is `global-map`.
- The key description of the key `<right>` is gotten with `(kbd "<right">)`.

So this does what you want: `(lookup-key global-map (kbd "<right>"))`. It returns the symbol `right-char`.